# retrieve mms address number

Tags: android

In my application I'm able to get all MMS through code below, but I am not able to get the mms address. Can you guys/girls please help me?

```
    Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms"),null,null,null,date DESC);
    count = cursor.getCount();
    if (count > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        long messageId = cursor.getLong(0);
        long threadId = cursor.getLong(1);
        long timestamp = cursor.getLong(2);
        String subject = cursor.getString(3);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to get address from MMS. do something like this

in msgnumber pass your messageID.

```
String add="";
final String[] projection =  new String[] { "address", "contact_id", "charset", "type" };
final String selection = "type=137"; // "type="+ PduHeaders.FROM,

Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://mms").buildUpon();
builder.appendPath(String.valueOf(msgnumber)).appendPath("addr");

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    builder.build(),
    projection,
    selection,
    null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      add =  cursor.getString(0);
    }
```

Hope this will help.